# White haired female lead with pink magenta eye stone who turns back time after killed by some duke family who adopted her for using her

Tags: story-identification, time-travel, manga

It’s been a year since I read this. It was on a website that translates Korean comics (manhwa). The points I remember are:

- The female lead (FL) has white hair and pink magenta eyes, which is a mana stone, a symbol for her family generation
- In her past life, the FL was killed by a duke family with light blue hair, after making her the empress (replacing her position for the duke’s sister)
- The FL turns back time and be strong and cold hearted
- The FL is poor and from a fallen family (?)
- The FL has outstanding swordsmanship (?)
- **Went to an academy to study and met a new friend, a daughter from a rich count's family but has bad health condition (sick)**
- Met two possible male leads, one with golden hair (illegitimate son of the pope) and the other with black hair (grand duke)
- In the academy she seeks revenge against her friends who bullied her in her past life

The one in bold is the point I remembered the most from the manhwa.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where and when did you read this?

Comment: Hi, David. Thank you for your response. It’s been a year, and I read it on a website that translates Korean comics (Manhwa).